# Android Linear Layout is not visible

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a problem that i want to show the linear layout in parent after i check the condition. I want to show linear layout `android:id="@+id/linearIndex"` in the body of parent layout. Here the code.

> The Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/lstep3">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/linearIndex"> //THE LAYOUT I WANT TO SHOW
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Jumlah Kasus Tambahan di Lokasi PE"
        android:textColor="@color/teal"
        />
    <!-- daftar gejala yang dimasukkan-->
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:id="@+id/listvievadvance2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"></ListView>

    <!-- form gejala-->
    <!-- form data gejala-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@color/accent_501">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pilih Lokasi"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/lokasiPilih"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtLocLain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lokasi lain"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:hint="Lokasi lain"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lokasiLain"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tanggal PE"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:hint="Tanggal PE"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tglPE"
            android:editable="false"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Jumlah Kasus tambahan"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:hint="Masukan jumlah kasus"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/jmlKasusTambah"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/btambahLokasi"
            android:text="Tambah"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/teal"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the java file

> Function that show visibility of layout

```
 private void checkIndexOrNot(){

    Log.i("Value :", String.valueOf(campak.getSurveilans().getStatusKasus()));

    if(Integer.parseInt(campak.getSurveilans().getStatusKasus()) == 1) {
        linearIndex.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        linearIndex.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

I know it's look like no problem, but the function that show visibility of layout does not work. The layout does not show after check condition. The logic of the condition that check from DB is working fine, no error.
I put the checkIndexOrNot() in onCreate() function.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: because the root `LinearLayout` with id `lstep3` is alway gone. Remove `android:visibility="gone"` in `lstep3` and you will see your LinearLayout

Comment: Yep, that's it. It's parent is `gone` so just remove that. You, dude, should write the answer and get it accepted @PhanVanLinh.

Comment: Thank you very much, i accept your answer @PhanVanLinh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parent layout of linearIndex has `gone` as default property mean it will not be visible. To show children views, the parent layout must be visible. So either set both layouts to visible programatically or just remove the `visibility="gone"` from `lstep3`

Comment: Yeah you are right, i ask my friend and his answer same as yours. So, is it okay if i set visibilty lstep3 in java GONE but in xml i remove visibility="gone"  ? So, I set the layout in java.

Comment: Well you can do that but if you set the visibility of linearIndex to visible, you also have to set the visibility of lstep3 to visible.

Comment: Okay, i will try it. Thank you anyway! @babadaba

Comment: I really thank to you, it's working. Thank you very much! @babadaba

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `android:visibility="gone"` from root layout.

Change this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/lstep3">
```

To this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lstep3">
```